# How to pass id to Form Request in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Im trying to update a record in the database, and im using Form Request to validate unique fields, but I cant pass the id to that Form because im just using the route like this:

```
Route::resource('ganado/engorde', 'GanadoController')->middleware('auth');
```

In my update controller:

```
public function update(GanadoEditFormRequest $request, $id)
{
    $bovino = Ganado::findOrFail($id);
    ...
}
```

This is my form request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'codigo_ganado' =>  ['required', 

            Rule::unique('ganado')
                   ->ignore($this->id, 'id_ganado')
                   ->where('lote_actual', $this->lote_actual)
                   ->where('ganaderia', $this->ganaderia)
            ],
    ];
}
```

I tried to pass directly the id = "85" just to check if this "ignore" thing its working and im getting and error too=

`id` <> 85 instead of `id` = 85.

How I can ignore the current updating record the right way?

**Edit:**

This is my "Ganado" table:

[image]

Comment: did u used something like this `url.com/ganado/engorde/85` to find your item?

Comment: yeah my update controller its working fine, this is an example: `http://ganaderia.test/ganado/engorde/85/edit` @Atlas-Pio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since i don't know how your code is look like you might wanna try this :

```
public function rules()
{
      $id = $this->route('id')
      // Or
      $id = $this->route('engorde')  
    return [
        'codigo_ganado' =>  ['required', 

            Rule::unique('ganado')
                   ->ignore($id, 'id_ganado')
                   ->where('lote_actual', $this->lote_actual)
                   ->where('ganaderia', $this->ganaderia)
            ],
    ];
}
```

So base on your `Ganado` table your primary table is `id_ganado`, which laravel recognize always tables with `id` as primary table, so you might need to add

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id_ganado';
```

Edit : Update to `ignore($id.',id_ganado')`

Comment: ok the second one its working and im getting the id, but still getting the unique validation message, just to check if im getting the id I removed the 'id_ganado' to get sql error that id column its unknown and here I can check that im getting the id, why still isnt working to ignore current record?

Comment: Here is the error that im saying: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from ganado where codigo_ganado = 0604 and id <> 85 and lote_actual = Lote-1 and ganaderia = VS)` just to check if im getting the correct id

Comment: yeah thats why i asked that later in the question, because I tried passing directly the id just to check if it was working and it was not working. Already updated the question with the table.

Comment: Already have defined the primary key like that way in my model @Atlas-Pio

Comment: mmm you mean with the -> after the ignore word? because thats a wrong way to put it

Comment: @Aux1234 ah no, sorry, without `->` i was thinking to something else :))) now just like you did before, just add coma before your table id `ignore($id.',id_ganado')

Comment: ok I tried that with the coma and was getting another error, but later I tried updating with new data that record and then tried again with the same information and now its working, I dont know what was going on but now its working fine like the way you put it in the answer, thank you for your help!

Comment: If you don't know what's your route name is `$this->route()->parameterNames()`...